# Refresh clipboard data?

Tags: refresh, tableau-api, clipboard

Hi Tableau Users and Experts,

I am hoping to get some clarity about how clipboard works. I am building a dashboard where data comes from multiple excel sheets. I have a worksheet (say A) where i bring in data needed from these excel sheets (like a vlookup but with more calculations). My next steps involve building a pivot from worksheet A. I was able to copy data from worksheet A to clipboard and use that as data source and build the pivot i needed. This was much quicker and avoided potential complex logic to count these records. My question here now is that i am trying to have the clipboard data refresh everytime worksheet A is refreshed with new data.

Is there a way to have the clipboard data refresh or link to the worksheet it is copied from?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Shikhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for Tableau to automatically refresh the clipboard. Architecturally, the clipboard is a function of the operating system. The clipboard function is invoked in Tableau once you have clicked on certain elements or the whole worksheet, then hitting the appropriate shortcut key or menu item. Tableau does not expose an API to invoke the functionality.

If your end goal is to allow the end user to export data though, there are plenty of different ways to accomplish that task automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My end goal is to avoid doing the complex calculations again to generate the pivot and reuse an existing worksheet table as data source. Thats where i bumped into clipboard, Are you aware of any other approach?